# Objective-C select part of array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, xcode

I am quite new to xcode / objective-c and I am facing a problem for a while now.

In my application I have a Json array receiving from my server, I send the array to the secondViewController by segue. This all goes right.

In my secondViewController I receive the array and select the part I needed by;

```
self.excersiseSection = [self.schemeData objectForKey:@"user_excersise_sections"];
```

This outputs the part of the array I've pushed to this controller so that's allright. Now, I want
to select the nested 'exercises' array (to print my table cells) in this array I have tried to do it like the code above with the index 'exercises' but no success.

```
{
    "user_training_days": [
        {
            "day_id": 1,
            "day_name": "Monday",
            "training": "trainingsdag",
            "user_excersise_sections": [
                {
                    "section_title": "Legs",
                    "exercises": [
                        {
                            "exercise_title": "Leg press",
                            "excercise_sets": "4",
                            "excercise_reps": "12",
                        }
                    ]
                },...etc
```

Comment: `user_excersise_sections` holds an array of dictionaries, so you can potentially have more than one array of `exercises`.  How do you want to handle that?

Comment: True, if needed I can rebuild the jSon array if it makes things more simple. What I am trying to reach is getting the exercises in an array so I can print them in the TableViewCell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code that will iterate over your json, and simple print it out

```
for (NSDictionary *section in excersiseSection) {
        NSLog(@"--- section_title: %@", section[@"section_title"]);
        for (NSDictionary *excercise in section[@"exercises"]) {
            NSLog(@"----- exercise_title: %@", excercise[@"exercise_title"]);
            NSLog(@"----- excercise_sets: %@", excercise[@"excercise_sets"]);
            NSLog(@"----- excercise_reps: %@", excercise[@"excercise_reps"]);
        }
}
```

This should help you, to construct your tableview.

**EDIT:**
Here is a complete solution to render your tableView.
1) Create a TableViewController in strotybaord, and assign a Custom class in storyboard.
2) Paste below code in the class
3) You are ready to go! :)

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return self.excersiseSection.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.excersiseSection[section][@"exercises"] count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.excersiseSection[section][@"section_title"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    NSDictionary *excercise = self.excersiseSection[indexPath.section][@"exercises"][indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = excercise[@"title"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sets: %@, Reps: %@",
                                 excercise[@"excercise_sets"], excercise[@"excercise_reps"]];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've checked out the code (it produces the log in good order) and tried to implement it in my UITableViewCell function but I guess I need some more help to figure out how to actually print these into the cell. Not the most easy array for a beginner I guess:)

Comment: @Freshtea How you put the value into the table view depends on whether the table view is cell based or view based. By default, new table views created with Xcode 6 are view based, previously they were cell based. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your data model is structured, but couldn't you try something like the following:

```
self.excersiseSection = [[[self.schemeData objectForKey:@"user_excersise_sections"] objectAtIndex:0]  objectForKey:@"exercises"];
```

Just chain the calls together. Note that this won't work if `user_excersise_sections` and `exercises` are not `NSArray` objects.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest creating particular classes like `UserTrainingDay`, `UserExcersiseSection` and `Excercise` and use for example [Mantle](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle) framework to establish mapping between your JSON and model classes.